# Build my library in JavaScript/Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I will appropriate your help in creating my library in JavaScript and using Dojo.
It seems to me like a beginner problem but I can't seem to find the problem.

I am trying to create a library that is named 'edm'

The EDM.js is very simple:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"

], function(declare) {


    var EDM = declare("EDM", {

        constructor: function() {
            console.log("Hi EDM lib")
        },

        sayHi: function() {
            console.log("Hi EDM lib")
        }
    });

    edm = new EDM();
    return edm;
});
```

The index.html to load it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script src="../src/EDM.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the main.js to use the edm is:

```
var newObject = edm;
```

The idea is basically to be able to use edm as prefix for the functions in EDM.js file.

However, when loading the index.htm file I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: edm is not defined"

I will appropriate any direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Dojo AMD loader in stead of loading the file yourself. Remove the following `<script>` tag:

```html
<script src="../src/EDM.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then write the following code in `main.js`:

```js
require([ "../src/EDM" ], function(edm) {
    var newObject = edm;
});
```

The advantages of doing it this way is the following:

- No need to add `<script>` tags that slow down the page when loading
- No additional objects are added to the global scope

Of course, because no objects are on global scope, you cannot retrieve the `edm` object directly. That's why you got that `ReferenceError`.

---

To answer your question from the comments: yes and no. Actually, you're already adding `edm` to the **global scope** in `EDM.js` because you didn't put `var` in front of the following statement:

```
edm = new EDM();
```

**However**, the `define()` callback is only executed if it's called from the Dojo AMD loader inside a `require()` function. So that actually means that you have to load the AMD module first and then you will be able to access `edm` from global scope.

So in your case, the following will work as well:

```
require([ "../src/EDM" ], function(bla) {
    var newObject = edm;
});
```

As you can see in the example above, we call our module `bla`, however, because you added it to global scope in `EDM.js`, it's now available. But, in order to add it to the global scope you have to properly load the module.

But be careful, adding objects to global scope is usually not encouraged, because they can be manipulated from any code which makes it hard to debug. There are a lot of other reasons why global variables are not a good idea, you can probably find a lot more information about it on the web.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri, this method is working. I do have one more question, is it possible to make the edm object accessible in the console (of chrom for example) in some way? Maybe I can create a global object in the EDM.js that will expose the edm object?

Comment: Yes and no, you actually already added it to global scope in `EDM.js`, but that will only be executed if you call it from the AMD loader. A more detailed explanation can be found in my answer.